# Multiple KnockoutJs components on the same page running individually

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout and struggling with having multiple instances of a component on a single page.

**Background.** Component gets an array of objects from a data service dynamically. Depending on user action, the component might need to re-render the array (new objects provided), therefore the array is an observable one.

**Problem.** There have to be multiple instances of the component on the page, however they have to work independently. Even though initially they receive the same array of objects.

I've created a simple example that would illustrate the problem.

HTML.

```
Emulate data service call: 
<button data-bind="click: getData">PULL</button><br>

Component 1:
<item-picker params="items: itemsArray"></item-picker>

Component 2:
<item-picker params="items: itemsArray"></item-picker>
```

JavaScript.

```
ko.components.register("item-picker", {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = params.items;
    self.addPerson = function() {
      self.items.push({
        name: "New at " + new Date()
      });
    };
  },
  template: "<button data-bind='click: addPerson'>Add</button><div data-bind='foreach: items'><p data-bind='text: name'></p></div>"
});


// top level viewmodel
var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.itemsArray = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.getData = function(){
    self.itemsArray([]);
    self.itemsArray.push({name: 'Bert'}, {name: 'Charles'}, {name: 'Denise'});
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

The example is also available on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ignas/14jgksj0/6/

**EDIT**
I should have mentioned that data service call is async, and data may be received later than the page load, and also user is able to force data re-retrieval (using different parameters for example). I've updated code snippets and the example on JSFiddle accordingly.

**Question.** In the JSFiddle example, how can I make components work independently? 
I.e. Adding a new name to "Component 1" should not add a name to "Component 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new observable array wrapper *and* inner array in your constructor:

```
self.items = ko.observableArray(params.items().slice(0));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dx6b6nvy/

There's two layers in your current structure:

1. An `observableArray` instance inside `vm.itemsArray`
2. An underlying, regular, array

Currently, all your components are modifying (2) via (1). To make sure each component holds its own, independent, selection, you'll have to create new arrays.

To create a new `observableArray`, you call `ko.observableArray` again. To create a copy of the original list, (note that the object references are still the same!), I've used `slice`.

**edit:**

The approach above decouples the component from the original array. If you want to keep the relation but not modify the source, here's what you can do:

In your component:

```
self.myItems = ko.observableArray([]);
self.items = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return params.items().concat(self.myItems());
});
```

You push to `myItems`, which will trigger an update of the computed. Any changes to the source observable array *also* trigger updates. You can even add a sort, if you like.

Comment: This sounded like a really promising solution, and it's my bad not to mention that data service call is async and can be re-triggered by user at any time. I've updated my question. Do you have an idea how to make an array wrapper in such case?

Comment: Create an observable array called myItems that addItem pushes to. Create a computed array that does a concat of myItems and parent.items(). Use the last, computed array in your foreach bind.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my weekend! :) Your solution guided me to solving the problem. The final bit I had to fix was DTOs instantiation, and it works now :)